# Infinite field which is not a metric space

Tags: topological-vector-spaces

Are there any infinite fields which are not metric spaces (other than the discrete topology)?

If so, why must a finite-dimensional vector space over this field be locally compact?

Comment: Every non empty set can be a metric space.

Comment: Fair enough. I was looking for spaces with a more "natural" metric.

Comment: "Metric space" is a structure, not a property. You want to ask something like "are there any infinite fields which cannot be given the structure of metric spaces," and of course the answers below show that the answer is no without more compatibility required between the field operations and the metric. See http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Norm_on_a_field for a common choice of such compatibilities.

Comment: @ajotatxe: every set can be a metric space. The empty set has a unique metric. Here it is:

Comment: @QiaochuYuan That helps a lot.  Is it just assumed that if there isn't a nice metric then the field is discrete?  Lang just states that any finite-dimensional vector space is locally compact wihtout any elaboration.

Comment: @jaebond: it depends on context. Lang might have had in mind specifically vector spaces over locally compact fields (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_field).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you. I would like to accept your comments if you would post them as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Any discrete space is locally compact, and finite dimensional vector spaces over a field with the discrete topology also has the discrete topology.

I think what you want to consider are metrics which induces a topology with respect to which the field operations are continuous.

I'm no expert on this, but you might be interested in 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_field

I believe fields like $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$ and its finite extensions are examples of infinite fields which do not admit a metric w.r.t. to which the field operations are continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Every non empty set can be a metric space. Just define
$$d(x,y)=\left\{
\begin{array}{lcl}
0&\text{ if }&x=y\\
1&\text{ if }&x\neq y
\end{array}
\right.$$